# How to change a constant in mysql to a constant?

Tags: mysql, variables

Within my mysql script,

I am creating a user as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE fire;
```

## after creating a table called Table1, privileges are changed

```
GRANT SELECT ON fire.Table1 TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```

In this case, fire is hardcoded, however, say in the future, I created a  mysql database called called "ice" and I wanted to reuse the script above, but I want the below line to this time grant privileges for fire.TABLE1, but in this case, it is really "ice.TABLE1". How do I make mysql think that "fire" means some other variable without having to change "fire" to "ice" everywhere on my script?

```
 GRANT SELECT ON fire.Table1 TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not include the database name in your grant scripts, but issue a `use dbname` statement to set the default database for your scripts to whatever database you want to work with.

As [mysql manual on grant statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) says:

> If you use ON * syntax (rather than ON *.*), privileges are assigned at the database level for the default database. An error occurs if there is no default database.

So, your script would look like:

```
USE fire;
GRANT SELECT ON Table1 TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```